# Como traducir los mensajes que realizo en el siguiente código, a español?

Tags: json, validación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Comunidad como puedo traducir los mensajes de error que me retorna una validación que realizo
de un archivo Json vs un esquema, estos errores los necesito para mostrar ak usuario final para que pueda corregir el archivo JSON.

Comment: consulta, esos mensajes son los log que te retorna la consola?

Comment: Hola, es una prueba que estoy haciendo en consola, los errores que vez son validaciones que se hacen al archivo JSON comparado con un Esquema Json para decirle al usuario final lo que esta armando mal en el archivo.